# Unstable download speed (connection) when scraping webpages using Jsoup

Tags: java, connection, jsoup

I am currently scraping webpages with a program I wrote in Java using Jsoup. The program needs to scrape about 450 urls (it's not that much).

The problem is that I am getting **very unstable download speed** when scraping.

For example, the first 7 urls would get scraped **instantly within 2 seconds** with a download speed of nearly **1MB/s**, but then the download speed suddenly reduces down to **0.4KB/s** or **EVEN 0KB/s**, causing the program to take 13 seconds to scrape a url. This sort of fluctuation occurs constantly and is resulting in severe slow-down of the program.

This is not my internet connection issue because it is happening with both my work and home wireless internet. And even when the current network speed indicator displays that the download speed is **0KB/s**, if I open up a webpage through my browser the page loads instantly with the download speed suddenly **increasing** again to **1MB/s**. But this increase causes no effect on my program and the program is still very slow to scrape the urls.

What could be the problem? Is there anything I need to configure to ensure a constant download speed for my scraping program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard problem strongly related to external resources (the urls you need to download).

To solve it you can create a pool of threads that make simultaneous downloads of different resources. Downloading simultaneously give you more possibilities to reach the limit of your bandwith also if a single download is very slow.

Total download time will decrease to a value closer to your bandwith capabilities.

Here a basic minimal example.

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
```

Remember to start first the server and after the client.

---

Here are some links to the Thread Pools that is possible to use as a start point to implement a thread pool to download many urls at the same time:

- [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html)
- [Jenkov tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-pools.html) (a very good one)
- [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-)

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. Would you be able to provide me with more information on downloading with threads? A link to a useful tutorial would suffice! :)

Comment: I edited my answer to give you some starting point to do that

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! I will definittely check them out :)

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the program is limited by the memory. Try increasing the heap space while starting the Java process.

Comment: How download speed can be increased with heap space?

Comment: If there is no space for reading the response, garbage collector would be running trying to free space. Check if that is the problem.

Comment: Also check if the server response is itself slow. If you know the URLs that are slow, try opening them on the browser and check the response time.

Comment: The problem is not that... it seems a real download speed problem. Not all sites answer at the same speed. A huge url to download will cause an OutOfMemoryError if the complete url is mantained in memory. If the url is parsed step by step the time lost in garbage collection is relatively few compared to IO operations (like downloading the url)

Comment: hmm...increasing the heap size does not seem to solve the problem :(